# How do I make RefreshIndicator disappear?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this code that has the parent widget `Homepage` and the child widget `CountryList`. In `CountryList`, I have created a function that uses an API to get a list of countries. I felt like enabling a `RefreshIndicator` in the app, so I had to modify the `Homepage` widget and add `GlobalKey` to access `getCountryData()` function of `CountryList` widget. The `RefreshIndicator` has done its job well. But the problem now is that when I pull and use the `RefreshIndicator` in the app, the `getCountryData()` function is called, but even after showing all data in the list, the circular spinner doesn't go (shown in the screenshot).[image: App Screenshot]

So, could anyone please suggest me a way to make the spinner go?
The code of `main.dart` containing `Homepage` widget is given below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'country_list.dart';
GlobalKey<dynamic> globalKey = GlobalKey();

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Homepage()));

class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("List of countries"), actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite), onPressed: (){},)
      ],),
      body: RefreshIndicator(child: CountryList(key:globalKey), onRefresh: (){globalKey.currentState.getCountryData();},),
    );
  }
}
```

And the code of `country_list.dart` containing `CountryList` widget is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
class CountryList extends StatefulWidget {
  CountryList({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CountryListState createState() => _CountryListState();
}

class _CountryListState extends State<CountryList> {
  List<dynamic> _countryData;
  bool _loading = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this.getCountryData();
  }

  Future<String> getCountryData() async {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"));
    var decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      _countryData = decodedResponse;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _loading?Center(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: <Widget>[CircularProgressIndicator(), Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),), Text("Loading data...", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),)],)):ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _countryData.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: SvgPicture.network(_countryData[index]['flag'], width: 60.0,),
            title: Text(_countryData[index]['name']),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `return` here:

```
Future<String> getCountryData() async {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.encodeFull("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"));
    var decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      _countryData = decodedResponse;
      _loading = false;
    });

    return 'success';
    }
```

and here:

```
body: RefreshIndicator(
    child: CountryList(key: globalKey),
    onRefresh: () {
      return globalKey.currentState.getCountryData();
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for remaining so patient and helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

The onRefresh callback is called. The callback is expected to update the scrollable's contents and then complete the Future it returns. The refresh indicator disappears after the callback's Future has completed, I think you should return `Future<String>` from `getCountryData`.

Comment: What should I exactly return? I tried returning a string "success". But it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I had the same problem that @SagunRajLage had, and that was because I wasn't putting the **_return inside the onRefresh() method_**. 
Explained with the above's example: 
I was doing:
`onRefresh: () {
       globalKey.currentState.getCountryData();
    },` 
instead of
     `onRefresh: () {
      return globalKey.currentState.getCountryData();
    },`
Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the indicator, just return some future because it needs to return a `Future<void>` value.
For Example:

```
onRefresh:(){
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
}
```

This actually removes the indicator after 1 second.